# wp7 c# LoadCompleted not firing

Tags: c#, events, windows-phone-7, oauth

I'm trying to figure out if an oauth-page has loaded.

Therefore I let my webbrowser navigate to:

`"https://api.munzee.com/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=" + API.ClientID + "&redirect_uri=" + API.RedirectUri;`

which redirects first to "https://api.munzee.com/oauth/signin" displaying a simple formular like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
  <img src='https://static-cdn-munzee.netdna-ssl.com/images/munzee-logo.svg' style='width: 160px;'/>
  <p>
  The application <strong>my WP7 App</strong> would like to access your munzee.com player account.<br/>
  This application won't be able to access or store your login credentials in any way.<br/>
  Authorization for this application can be revoked at any time by visiting <a href='http://www.munzee.com/revoke'>http://www.munzee.com/revoke</a>.
  </p>
  <p><strong>Please sign in:</strong></p>
  <form method='POST'>
    <p>Username:<br/><input type='text' name='username'/></p>
    <p>Password:<br/><input type='password' name='password'/></p>
    <p><input type='submit' value='Login'/></p>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the LoadCompleted event **doesn't** fire, once the document was loaded (I can see the page loaded successfully in the browser). The navigated-event fires just fine...

Here is my code so far:

```
    private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackGroundBrowser.Navigate(
            new Uri("https://api.munzee.com/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=" +
            API.ClientID + "&redirect_uri=" + API.RedirectUri, UriKind.Absolute)
        );
    }

    private void BackGroundBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("BackGroundBrowser_LoadCompleted: " + BackGroundBrowser.Source.ToString());
        // do some smart things...
    }

    private void BackGroundBrowser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackGroundBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("about:blank", UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    private void BackGroundBrowser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("BackGroundBrowser_Navigated: " + BackGroundBrowser.Source.ToString());
    }
```

If you are interested in this topic, let me know and I'll provide you my clientID and redirectUri for testing purposes. But I don't want those information to be public.

Why is this happening and is there a way to determine if the page has loaded? My only idea for now is to create a loop in the "navigated" handler, checking for some page related values and firing the event manually if the condition matches.

But this seems to be a bit murky, since this page can change and I don't want to update the App everytime they e.g. change some styles...

Answer (score 0):

The `Loaded` Event refers to the `WebBrowser` control. It is fired when the control is loaded in the visual tree.

It is not the same as a DOMLoaded event in the browser.

There is no event fired that is equivalent to the DOM Loaded event.
The nearest you can get is to monitor the `Navigated` event and then wait a short time before accessing the page's content.
Note that you need to wait as the `Navigated` event will fire before the page has finished being "loaded". That is before the browser engine has finished laying out the content and any javascript on (or linked from) the page has run.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.loadcompleted(v=vs.95).aspx


"Top-level navigation occurs when the Source property is set or Navigate is called.
If an error occurs, such as the content cannot be found, the LoadCompleted event is raised when the error is returned from the Web server. ... For more information about handling events, see Events Overview for Silverlight."